# How can I resolve 1290 error code in MYSQL 8.0

Tags: mysql

I've searched and found several proposed solutions to this however, none work.

I'm attempting to run the commands below:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'd:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\pa_ballot_request'
INTO TABLE pa_ballot_request
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

I'm getting the 1290 error: MySQL server is running with the –secure-file-priv”

The secure-file-priv line is pointing to the directory where my *.csv is located yet I still get the error.

I've tried commenting out the secure-file-priv line in my.ini and I continue to get the error.
I've turned off the Safe Updates option in MySQL Workbench.

I'm running MySQL 8.0.21

Answer (score 1):

Instead of commenting it, change the value of the variable into null.
In the notepad where you find secure-file-priv line, write the following line:

```
secure-file-priv=""
```

This solves the problem in MySQL 8.0

After solving this, you may get Error 29 while execution, which is incorrect file path. This can be solved by using `\\` in place of `\` in the path line.

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted changing all of the `\` to `/` as well as `\\` which I had seen other mentioning has worked for them on older versions of MySQL. This modification did not work for me.

Comment: Hi James. "Me too" is not considered an answer, so I deleted that part. But the rest of your post could be seen as a partial answer. For that you should describe how much your attempts worked. I assume that they did not work (guessing from the part I deleted.) Please [edit] to explicitly provide that info.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance Yunnosch. It's my understanding that my response would have been more fitting as a comment on the original post. Is that proper etiquette? If so, I'll need to get more active!

Comment: Get more active, get that commenting privilege; you will enjoy it. Here I was commenting that your post can be seen as a partial answer (i.e. a participation in the answering process, without giving a full answer, while there is no full answer yet). That is basically accepted as being an answer. I am just explaining things - guidance as you wrote. Hve a look at [answer], [ask] and take the [tour] to increase your chances for upvotes. Good look and have fun.